# HTTPD ReverseProxy ProxyPass directive ending in wrong Location header

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

HTTPD is configure as following:

```
#redirectder edit Location "(^http[s]?://)([^/]+)" "" port 80 to secure
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mitestui02.sn.test.net
    #ServerAlias server server2.domain.com server2
    ServerAdmin support.p240@test.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/test/iiq/appserver/apache-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/test/iiq/appserver/apache-access.log common

    Redirect /identityiq/ https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/identityiq/
    Redirect / https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/identityiq/

</VirtualHost>

#redirect to port 8080 on localhost
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mitestui02.sn.test.net
    # ServerAlias mitestui02 mitestui02.sn.test.net
    ServerAdmin support.p240@test.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLEngine On
    #allow only tls
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...
    
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/opt/test/iiq/appserver/secure/ssl/web-iiq.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/opt/test/iiq/appserver/secure/ssl/apache-iiq.key

    Redirect /identityiq/ https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/
    Redirect / https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/identityiq/

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /identityiq/ http://localhost:8080/identityiq/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^OPTIONS
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

    <If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.jsf/?[?\s]#">
        Header add X-UI-Source "mitestui02"
        Header add X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
        Header add Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        Header add Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'; geolocation 'none'; usb 'none'; payment 'none'; document-domain 'none'; camera 'none'; display-capture 'none'; ambient-light-sensor 'none'"
        Header add Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=(), camera=(), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=()"
        Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
        Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
        Header add X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

        Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure; SameSite=Strict"
        Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure; SameSite=Strict"
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I connect to the front-end URL, **https://mitest.sn.test.net/** I get redirected with a response code 302 and Location header pointing to **https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/identityiq/** instead of  **https://mitest.sn.test.net/identityiq/** .

This doesn't happen when connecting to **https://mitest.sn.test.net/identity/** directly.

I have tried with different ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives and also rewriting the Location header, nothing seems to help.
Thanks

Comment: The 302 you mention seem to match with the directive you have defined in your https virtualhost:

    Redirect / https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/identityiq/ . It is better if you explain what you want to do in all cases. What do you want if you request / or if you request /identityiq/ etc and stay out of possibly conflicting redirect and proxypass directives, that is, if you have a proxypass directive to a path, why do you also have a redirect for it?

Comment: Thanks for the input. When the user connects to:  https://mitest.sn.test.net/ or  https://mitest.sn.test.net/identityiq (there are pointing to the DNS name pointing to the load balancer) the request should be handled by one of the servers in the backend (for example mitestui02) with no redirection, for the user he should still view in the url the URL mitest, this happens when the user connects to https://mitest.sn.test.net/identityiq  but no when connecting to  https://mitest.sn.test.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seemed to be related to the Redirect directives.
We removed them and added the following for 443:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    # Redirect / to /identiyiq
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /identityiq
```

We removed them and added the following for 80:

```
   Redirect permanent / https://mitestui02.sn.test.net/
```

Now it is working as expected.

Comment: Why check for http protocol in ssl virtualhost? It makes no sense. For the future, I would suggest to stick to either rewrite or redirect not both.